# Searching for a specific month in a metadata saved as Timestamp (Wp_Query)

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I need to keep the payment dates for a post type I created called "Payments." For this, I created a meta key called "expected_payment_date". I save the expected payment dates as timestamp. For example, I keep the date 2020-05-15 as 1589490000.

I want to list all payments that should be made in a given month using Wp_Query. I try the method below for this, but I got no results. Do you know how I can do this?

```
$month = '2020-05';
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => array( 'payments' ),
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_status'     => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query '     => array(
        'key' => 'expected_payment_date',
        'value' => $month,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
```

Note: I tried other comparisons like = EXIST in the Compare section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a long search. Thank you very much to Misha Rudrastyh who gave me a great idea in my solution. You can [check out the great guide](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html) that he prepared for meta_query.

**Here is the solution:**

First, get the first and last day of the month as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541938/how-to-get-the-first-and-last-days-of-a-given-month) (thanks for Francois Deschenes).

```
$month = '2020-05';

// First day of the month.
$first_day = strtotime( date('Y-m-01', strtotime($month)) );
// Last day of the month.
$last_day = strtotime( date('Y-m-t', strtotime($month)) );
```

I use it as a timestamp because I keep the expected payment dates in this way. For more details, I suggest you check Misha's guide.

Once you have the dates correctly fetched, all you have to do is prepare the wp_query arguments.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'       => array( 'payments' ),
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_status'     => array( 'publish' ),
    'meta_query '     => array(
        'key' => '_eo_payment_expected_date',
        'value' => array( $first_day, $last_day ),
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    )
);
```

That is all.